# Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'string'

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio-2015, user-controls

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
 private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string login = loginTextBox.Text;
        string password = passwordtextBox.Text;

        myLogin m = new myLogin(login, password);

        **if (m.getX != "" && m.getY != "")**
        {
             displayLabel.Text = "The information entered is:";
             resultLogin.Text =
             "Login: " + m.getX();
             resultPassword.Text =
             "Password: " + m.getY();
             } // end if
         else
           displayLabel.Text = "Enter information above";
         } // end method OkButton_Click
```

The problem is where the code is surrounded with "**". Is there a way to check if the textbox is empty without getting the error?

Edit:

myLogin looks like this:

```
 public class myLogin 
{
    private readonly string login, password;
    public myLogin(string x, string y)
    {
        login = x;
        password = y;
    }

    public string getX()
    {
        return login;
    }

    public string getY()
    {

        return password;
    }
```

Comment: `m.getX() != ""` you want to *call* the method and compare its output

Comment: Don't know your `myLogin` class, but I guess `getX` and `getY` are no _properties_ but _methods_, so `m.getX() != "" && m.getY() != ""` should do the trick.

Comment: what does the myLogin class look like?

Comment: Instead of `getX` why not just use a read only property `public string Login { get; private set; }`?  Same with `getY()`.  Also those names aren't very descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

You want to *call* methods and compare their results:

```
 if (m.getX() != "" && m.getY() != "") ...
```

As a further improvement you may want to refactor *methods* into *properties*:

```
 //TODO: think on changing name "X" to "Login" 
 public string X { 
   get {
     return login;
   }
 } 

 //TODO: think on changing name "X" to "Password" 
 public string Y { 
   get {
     return password;
   }
 }
```

Having done this you can put as easy as

```
if (X != "" && Y != "") ...
```

Finally, just move all the logic on login/password validation into its own class:

```
// This class holds login/password: so it's it that responsible for validation
public class MyLogin() {
  public MyLogin(string login, string password) {
    if (null == login)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("login"); 
    else if (null == password)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("password"); 

    Login = login;
    Password = password; 
  }

  // Property with a readble name (what's X?)
  public string Login {
    get;
    private set;
  }

  // Property with a readble name (what's Y?)
  public string Password {
    get;
    private set;
  }

  public bool IsValid {
    get {
      return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Login) &&
             !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password); 
    }
  }
}
```

Please, notice how it's easy to work now:

```
private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  MyLogin m = new myLogin(loginTextBox.Text, passwordtextBox.Text);

  if (m.IsValid) 
  {
      displayLabel.Text = "The information entered is:";  
      resultLogin.Text = $"Login: {m.Login}";
      resultPassword.Text = $"Password: {m.Password}";
  }
  else 
      displayLabel.Text = "Enter information above";
}
```